# Using scipy.optimize how would I make a program with a dynamic function that takes in different strings to fit different curves?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to make a program which inputs a user inputted function and then tries to fit said function to a data set and frankly I'm having a hard time coming up with a solution I've tried using eval() however I'm not how to reconcile this with SciPy

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a normal function from an expression in string form with `compile()`:

```
fcn_code = compile("x + y", "<string>", mode="eval")
fcn = lambda x, y: eval(fcn_code)
fcn(1, 2)
```

If you need statements, check the documentation for `exec()`.